# i keep getting java.lang.illigalthreadexception?

Tags: java, exception, audio, error-handling

I want to create a simple audio player but I keep getting that exception, can anyone explain why?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Audioo {
  public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
  {
    try {
      InputStream im;
      im = new FileInputStream (new File ("name"));
      AudioStream audios = new AudioStream (im);
      AudioPlayer.player.start(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {                                          
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
    } 
  }      
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code - `AudioPlayer` class would help.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace as well. I assume you mean `IllegalThreadStateException`?

Comment: @Zyn - `sun.audio.AudioPlayer`. Would seem to be an import from the `sun.*` packages.

Comment: In the examples I've seen online, you'd need to pass your `audios` variable as an argument to the `start()` method.

Comment: This code seems fundamentally broken, is this your _real_ code? For example `AudioPlayer.player.start();` should most likely be `AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);`.

Comment: Do you need to initialize the player with something? `AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);` perhaps?

Comment: yup it worked , i just needed to change it into this AudioPlayer.player.start(audios); , thanks every one for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably `sun.audio.AudioPlayer` does not support audio format of the file you are trying to play.

I took your code, fixed `start()` with `start(audios)`, changed file name to the full path to sample wav file I downloaded from [here](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/Goldwave/addf8-Alaw-GW.wav), and it works for me.